# Can javascript in XSL FO file write to the document for processing with Apache FOP?

Tags: javascript, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I was trying to test using JavaScript scripts to add content to a template at the time of processing by a PDF render-er, specifically Apache FOP. I know that XSL can call a javascript file that can in turn call

```
document.write("<p>some text</p>");
```

which can be displayed easily in a web browser. Is it possible for your javascript function to write something to the document that is more like

```
document.write("<fo:block>some text</fo:block>");
```

Such that Apache FOP will be able to process and display that block in the output PDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.write` is a method of the `document` object exposed by browsers in `text/html` documents to script. XSLT does not have access to that document object and its method, not even with client-side XSLT done in the browser. The only option you have there is to have XSLT generate a HTML result document that then uses script to `document.write` something. And even that is restricted, for instance Mozilla browsers don't support `document.write` in the result document of an XSLT transformation, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XSL_Transformations_in_Mozilla_FAQ#What_about_document.write.3F.

As for Javascript with Apache FOP, no, I don't think there is any document object available. And I am not sure why you need script to create a `fo:block` element, with XSLT it suffices to use literal result element e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
  <fo:block>some text</fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The fo:block was just an example, i want to generate a barcode inside the template and place it in the pdf, I know how to do this using JQuery and Javascript, but i am not understanding how javascript fits in with the xsl fo stuff, is javascript really only useable for XSLT and not XSL FO? A lot of on-line resources seem contradictory.